# Push integer from Input to array

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to get the number pushed into the array but cant seem to link the input to the array any help please

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">
      <input type="text" name="input">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Add number</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="box" style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto"></div>
    <script>
      var number= [];
      function myFunction(){
        number.push=("myform")
        var x=document.getElementById("box");
        x.innerHTML=number.join('<br/>');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning, when you should be calling. On top of that you are fetching the value wrong.

```
number.push(document.getElementById('myform')['input'].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the id of the form as a string. You have to add the value of the field, so that you can get it later:

```
var number= []; 
function myFunction() 
{ 
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    number.push(input.value);

    var x=document.getElementById("box"); 
    x.innerHTML=number.join('<br/>'); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, this code is assigning the value of the input to the property 'push' on the object 'number'.

Comment: Ops... sorry. that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: i don't understand what you say. Actually i have the numbers  1,2,3.. after push to array using "items.push(values) ". its display like this. ['1','2','3,']. But  i want [1,2,3] like this how to do

Comment: To convert the values to `Number`s you will have to call `parseInt(value, base)` on them (eg.: `var num = parseInt(input.value, 10);`).